# open/close sidebar changing buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
 function w3_open() {
 document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("w3-button").style.display = "none"
 document.getElementById("w3-buttondos").style.display ="inline-block"

 }

 function w3_close() {
 document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("w3-buttondos ").style.display = "none"
 document.getElementById("w3-button").style.display ="inline-block"
 }
```

```html
<button class="w3-button w3-teal" onclick="w3_open()">&#9776;</button>
     <button class="w3-buttondos w3-teal" onclick="w3_close()">&#10006;</button>
```

it says me -> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: Is your code in the same document or do you use a seperate .js file? please provide some more code to reproduce it.

Comment: It seems your sidebar is missing. Can you provide it's markup? Did you your sidebar has the id `mySidebar` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById` does not target a node by its `class=""` but by its `id=""`

```
<button id="w3-button" class="w3-button w3-teal" onclick="w3_open()">&#9776;</button>
```

To target an element by its `class` you can use [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
document.querySelector(".w3-button")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `document.getElementById()` then you must declare id property in html element.
Like: id="w3-button"

```js
function w3_open() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("w3-button").style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById("w3-buttondos").style.display ="inline-block"
 }

 function w3_close() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("w3-buttondos").style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById("w3-button").style.display ="inline-block"
 }
```

```html
<button id="w3-button" class="w3-button w3-teal" onclick="w3_open()" hidden>&#9776;</button>
<button id="w3-buttondos" class="w3-buttondos w3-teal" onclick="w3_close()">&#10006;</button>
<div id="mySidebar">
  My Sidebar
</div>
```